# Spring autowiring issues on paramaterized class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been struggling with this issue for a while and have browsed a lot of articles, but couldnt figure out the solution. Appreciate your help with the issue below.

I need to be able to autowire the EntityManager in the service class, but throws an exception. The default constructor probably has issues because of type erasure and so I tried using a constructor with parameters to set the Type. How do I autowire EntityManager of type User?

```
public interface IEntityManager<T extends IDomain<ID>, ID extends Serializable> {

    T findById(ID id, boolean lock);

    T save(T entity);

    void delete(T entity);
}

public class EntityManager<T extends IDomain<ID>, ID extends Serializable> 
        implements IEntityManager<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> entity;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /*
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public EntityManager() {
        this.entity = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

    } */

    @Autowired(required=true)
    public EntityManager(Class<T> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}

@Service("UserService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired  
    EntityManager<User, Integer> entityManager;
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.dummy.persistence.manager.EntityManager com.test.dummy.service.UserServiceImpl.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.dummy.persistence.manager.EntityManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
```

Comment: check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368339/spring-3-2-autowire-generic-types)

Comment: Why aren't you using `@PersistenceContext`?

Answer (score 3):

Spring **cannot** deduce that it need to Inject `User.class` in the constructor of `EntityManager` to satisfy the depdenency in `UserServiceImpl`.

If you are using **Spring 4**, You can to define a bean of type `EntityManager<User, Integer>`:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
      @Bean 
      public EntityManager<User, Integer> userEntityManager() {
            new EntityManager(User.class);
      } 
}
```

**Edit:** 
Or define a [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) that will check for beans that require EntityManager as dependency, identify the required type, construct the new EntityManager bean for the required type and add it to the bean registry.

```
 @Component
 public class MyEntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements
                                                       BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {


   @Override
   public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
       throws BeansException {
     for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
       final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = getOriginatingBeanDefinition(
           beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName));
       final Class<?> beanClass = getClass(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
       if (beanClass != null) {
         ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(beanClass, new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
           public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

             if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Autowired.class) || field.isAnnotationPresent(
                 Inject.class)) {
               if (field.getGenericType() instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                 final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
                 final Class<?> rawType = (Class) parameterizedType.getRawType();
                 if (rawType.equals(EntityManager.class)) {
                   final Class<?> typeArgument = (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                   beanFactory.registerSingleton(field.getName(), new EntityManager(typeArgument));
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         });
       }
     }
   }

   private Class<?> getClass(String className) throws BeansException {
     if (className != null) {
       try {
         return Class.forName(className);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         throw new BeanInitializationException("beanClass not found", e);
       }
     }
     return null;
   }

   private BeanDefinition getOriginatingBeanDefinition(BeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
     while(beanDefinition.getOriginatingBeanDefinition() != null) {
       beanDefinition = beanDefinition.getOriginatingBeanDefinition();
     }
     return beanDefinition;
   }


   @Override
   public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {  }
 }
```

Finally, it looks like what you actually need is to use [Spring Data Jpa](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) which, in essence, lets you define a parameterized DAO by defining an interface like this:

```
package com.myapp.repository; 

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

You enable it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myapp.repository")
public class Config {


}
```

You then inject `UserRepository`:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

And Spring will inject a basic DAO implementation.

Comment: This is a great answer! However I think that you should mention that if there a multiple `EntityManager` beans, you need to either add `@Qualifier` along with `@Autowired`, or use Spring 4 which can deduce the correct bean based on the generic arguments.

Comment: Spring /can/ deduce types, but you need spring 4

Comment: @EngineerDollery Spring 4 can deduce type for injection against already define beans. It cannot deduce that it need to pass User.class to new EntityManager, unless you also define User.class as a bean.

Comment: The problem is I would have 20+ such service classes. Would I have to define a configuration for each of those service classes? Is there a generic solution or is that what you mean by using a BeanPostProcessor?

Comment: Yes, in theory you could implement a `BeanPostProcessor` to do that for you. Or you could use `Spring Data Jpa` which I think already provides what you are trying to implement (see updated answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use Spring Data JPA, but do you have an example of the BeanPostProcessor to give me an instance of a specific Type? I have a lot of service classes that needs to use the entity manager and would like to avoid creating repetitive code

Comment: @mrbean Check the updated answer for the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` that provide the missing functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much Ricardo for your help on this. I will try this out.

Answer (score -1):

You might be missing **@Component** annotation on your EntityManager class.

The autowired constructor requires a class entity which is not injected.

```
@Autowired(required=true)
public EntityManager(Class<T> entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
}
```

try

```
@Autowired(required=true)
    public EntityManager() {

    }
```

Comment: I tried that and I now get a different error:Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.Class]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Class] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Comment: There is no direct dependency for you Class<T> type which is why its failing.

Comment: I didnt downvote it. I am not sure if someone else did it. I just added my comment..I apologize if I did something by mistake.