# Singleton Bean instance by generic parameter

Tags: java, spring, generics

I would like to have a singleton bean instance by generic parameter based on a single `@Component` generic class.

(I am using Spring 4.)

**My code :**

I have an `interface` like this :

```
public interface Mapper<I, O> {
    ...
}
```

And multiple implementation of it which are Spring `@Component`s (singletons). Something like this :

```
@Component
public class MapperA implements Mapper<ClazzAI, ClazzAO> {
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class MapperB implements Mapper<ClazzBI, ClazzBO> {
    ...
}
```

where `ClazzAI`, `ClazzAO`, `ClazzBI` and `ClazzBO` are basic Java classes.

I have another Spring `@Component` (singleton) which have a `Mapper` `class` as a generic parameter :

```
@Component
public class TransformerImpl<I, O, M extends Mapper<I, O>> {

    /** The Mapper */
    protected final M mapper;

    @Inject
    private TransformerImpl(final M mapper) {

        this.mapper= mapper;
    }

    ...
}
```

and I would like to use it like this :

```
@Inject
private TransformerImpl<ClazzAI, ClazzAO, MapperA> transformerA;

@Inject
private TransformerImpl<ClazzBI, ClazzBO, MapperB> transformerB;
```

---

The problem :

But Spring is not able to instantiate those 2 objects because it founds 2 implementations of `Mapper` : `MapperA` and `MapperB` even if I specify which implementation I want as a generic parameter.

Any idea how to make it without the need of instantiate all of those beans in a `@Configuration` `class` ?

Comment: But you need two TransformerImpl beans anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking for a singleton but requiring two injection points

```
@Inject
private TransformerImpl<ClazzAI, ClazzAO, MapperA> transformerA;

@Inject
private TransformerImpl<ClazzBI, ClazzBO, MapperB> transformerB;
```

for differently constructed objects. That doesn't make much sense.

You now realize you need two beans. If you can't (don't want to) do it in a `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` factory methods, you'll need to declare (and scan) two separate `@Component` classes. (I made your parent constructor public here.)

```
@Component
class MapperATransformerImpl extends TransformerImpl<ClazzAI, ClazzAO, MapperA> {
    @Inject
    public MapperATransformerImpl(MapperA mapper) {
        super(mapper);
    }
}

@Component
class MapperBTransformerImpl extends TransformerImpl<ClazzBI, ClazzBO, MapperB> {
    @Inject
    public MapperBTransformerImpl(MapperB mapper) {
        super(mapper);
    }
}
```

When processing the injection target

```
@Inject
private TransformerImpl<ClazzAI, ClazzAO, MapperA> transformerA;
```

Spring will find the `MapperATransformerImpl`, which is of type `TransformerImpl<ClazzAI, ClazzAO, MapperA>` and inject that.

Comment: I understand that this behavior may be **strange** but it seems **legit** to me. I was trying **not** to define all `TransformerImpl`s and all `Mapper`s as `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class supposing this behavior was provided out of the box by Spring. However, I would rather use `@Bean` factory methods than implementing all `TransformerImpl` as Spring `@Components` as you suggest.

Comment: @Basemasta A singleton is a single bean, but you want two beans. You can use your single class to create both those beans, but not with `@Component` with singleton scope (not even with prototype scope actually).

Comment: well, what is "singleton" in the world of generics? `G<A>` and `G<B>` are two different types; it is legit to ask for a singleton per type. Erasure is not an excuse in a DI framework (that's somehow worth $100M:)

Answer (score 2):

Try with Spring 4. See  [Using generics as autowiring qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-generics-as-qualifiers)

**Edit**

Like @SotiriosDelimanolis explained in his answer, Spring 4 can use type parameter information as qualifiers to select which bean definition matches a particular injection point, but in the end, it will only match against bean definition with concrete type definitions. In your case, the problem is that you need a TransformerImpl bean definition for each concrete type you want to inject.

As an alternative to defining all bean definition explicitly, check my answer to  [Spring autowiring issues on paramaterized class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331213/spring-autowiring-issues-on-paramaterized-class/25332127#25332127)

Comment: Opps, I missed the part where you mentioned you are already using Spring 4.

Comment: The construction of the `TransformerImpl` bean is independent of the `@Inject` injection points that need it. As such, Spring has no idea which `Mapper` bean to use here and will complain that 2 of them exist.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, After reading your answer I realized I answered a similar question before. I just edited my answer with the explanation. You are, of course, right, the change I proposed before wouldnt make a difference.

Comment: I implemented a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` as you suggest. But it seems like it only allows Spring to **instantiate** the `TransformerImpl` beans (which is great by the way) but not telling Spring **how to inject them**. I am forced to use the `@Qualifier` annotation in order to tell Spring how to inject them based of the naming convention have I defined in the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. Any idea how to solve this in a more proper way ?